# Selenium WebDriver Firefox connect error for Linux OS

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium, xvfb, headless-browser

I have tried all solution suggested by Google. But still struggling to below issue. I have setup of PHPUnit-Selenium based automation framework using headless Firefox on RedHat Linux

Selenium Log Error :

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect
>   to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output
>   follows: Error: no display specified Error: no display specified

So far I tried:

```
updated version of selenium driver
updated version of firefox  
various selenium-firefox combinations using older versions
Xvfb  working fine
```

Please also let me know :

```
How i can verify firefox on port 7055 ?
Is etc/hosts file can have cause of this issue ?
```

Comment: export DISPLAY=:99.0

Comment: Hi @Deep123 did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am experiencing the same.  Many thanks